# Call another C++ function on the same .cpp file in android ndk

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Thanks in advance.
I have a Android ndk c++ file name native-lib.cpp just like

```
    extern "C"
    JNIEXPORT jstring

    JNICALL
    Java_foo_foo_foo_foo_HomeActivity_temp( JNIEnv *env, jobject  ){
        std::string password = getTempString();
        return  env->NewStringUTF( password.c_str() ); 
    }
    std::string getTempString(){
        return "temp_string";
    }
```

But it shows error on calling getTempString() that undeclared function getTempString();
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a declaration of `getTempString` before the first use. One way is to use a prototype

```
// prototype
std::string getTempString();

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring
JNICALL
Java_foo_foo_foo_foo_HomeActivity_temp( JNIEnv *env, jobject  ){
    std::string password = getTempString();
    return  env->NewStringUTF( password.c_str() ); 
}
std::string getTempString(){
    return "temp_string";
}
```